# PHP date function issues

Tags: php

I need to get date in the following format:

`Jan 21, 1990`

For that I used `date('M d, Y')` as mentioned on *php.net* but I am getting the complete time string including AM/PM time date etc.

```
<?php 
    echo date('DATE_FORMAT, strtotime($staff['Staff']['date_added'])'); 
?>
```

Comment: Works for me as it is: `Apr 15, 2013`

Comment: working for me .. error must be somewhere else ..

Comment: the function call is correct. post the full code so we can spot the error.

Comment: Yup, works just like this...

Comment: <?php echo date('DATE_FORMAT, strtotime($staff['Staff']['date_added'])'); ?>

Comment: pls double check your date function as above it is fine as you want..

Comment: in staff date - date is stored in  `Y m d H:i:s` format

Comment: you have wrong quotes in your function... double check that. And, post the code in your question, not in comments

Comment: how does `$staff['Staff']['date_added']` look like

Answer (score 4):

here is your answer

```
echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($staff['Staff']['date_added']));
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `date` function togther with `strtotime`**

```
$today = '1990/01/21';
echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($today))
```

**output will be**

```
Jan 21, 1990
```

Documentation
[date](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php)

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix two parameters of [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)  in one

Try this

```
<?php 
 echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($staff['Staff']['date_added'])); 
?>
```